# The Carbon Atoms in Your Body Turn into Silicon Atoms -- What Happens Next?

Tags: science-fiction, mythical-creatures

In [The Laundry Novel series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laundry_Files), basilisks and associated weapons and creatures turn their targets to stone by transmuting 10% of carbon to silicon. Ignoring the question of how, what effects would this actually have? It’s shown to generate massive amounts of heat, but I’m more interested in what kind of stone this would actually produce if used on a human. Note: it’s specifically carbon, not living things. Paint has been shown to ignite in the same way.

[SCORPION STARE](https://thelaundryfiles.fandom.com/wiki/SCORPION_STARE) is a weapons system based on reverse engineering basilisks and medusae:
"In the case of SCORPION STARE, about ten percent of the carbon nuclei in the target are randomly transformed into silicon nuclei as if by magic. Messy pyrotechnics ensue: gamma radiation, short-lived muons, some really pretty high-energy chemistry, and lots of heat. We worked out how to do it by reverse-engineering basilisks and medusae—animals and unfortunate people suffering from a peculiar, and very rare, brain tumor. Now we’ve got defensive camera-emplacements on every high street, networked and ready to be controlled centrally when the balloon goes up. Street cleaning by CCTV-controlled flame thrower.

The technology itself relies on a trick of quantum observation that temporarily replaces the carbon atoms of the target with that of silicon.  This causes an instantanieous chemical reaction, as carbon dioxide for example now becomes silicon dioxide, thus permanently altering the chemical make up of the entire object."

Comment: 10% of the carbon chosen at random, or the outermost, or what?

Comment: You might want to shake up the figures a bit, only 12% of [atoms in the body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_the_human_body) are carbon, so what you're suggesting is turning 1.2% of the body's atoms into another substance. That's not much considering that most of the body is water anyhow. Please enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways, welcome to worldbuilding.

Comment: Are you just asking about the Laundry File novel, or are you creating a world using the same principle as the one in the novel?

Comment: Can silicon and carbon form chains together? Because if not, every DNA molecule in your body would disintegrate instantly.

Comment: Is that 10% per attack? If so, how many attacks does the basilisk have? Or is the attack blocked by preexisting silicon (in which case, just haul enough jewelry)?

Comment: @johndvorak the question asks for effect on human body, not how to dodge the effect. So assume an unprepared human: what kind of stone (if any) results when our carbon is replaced with silicon at molecular level.

Comment: @SRM my question is how many atoms get replaced - 10% each six seconds or 10% once? Which atoms get replaced has already been asked.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I was answering the part about jewelry. :-)

Comment: @SRM that part wasn't a question ;-)

Comment: @johndvorak I know. So why did you bring it up?

Comment: @SRM is there a reason I shouldn't have brought it up?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. The average human doesn't contain more than 60g of DNA, but I don't think you'd survive too long without it.

Comment: @Rafael It'd wreak havoc with enzymes/neurotransmitters too no doubt, but I can't see it turning anything to stone as per the OP's idea.

Comment: Tried to look up what exactly the Laundry Files basilisks are supposed to do, but only found an excerpt from *The Rhesus Chart* which said *1*%.

Comment: When the bounty will end (because it seems we can't close questions with bounties o_x), I'll vote to close because asking about 3rd party worlds is off-topic ^^'. That is, if I don't forget it next week!

Comment: Why is it called the Laundry Basilisk when it turns stuff to stone and not laundry?

Comment: @Daron Laundry's about the novels' names, the "[Laundry Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laundry_Files)", not basilisks living in your laundry x).

Comment: This should be closed for asking about 3rd party worlds.

Comment: Nitpick: a silicon atom is 233% the mass of a carbon atom, so converting C to Si on a one-to-one basis requires an input of 1.3kg of matter for every 1kg of existing carbon. Assuming something nuclear is going on, this reaction would _consume_ lots of energy (=matter), not produce it.

Answer (score 15):

**People Soup**

[image]

Matthias says all the carbon is locked up in molecules in the person. This is correct.

Now turn each carbon atom into a silicon atom. The silicons  can no longer form the same molecules. The molecules fall apart into loose atoms -- Is this where the heat comes from? -- and the connections between the molecules also fall apart. The person turns into person soup.

Why person soup and not person powder? It's because over half the human body is made of water. And water contains no carbon so is still water after the basilisk gets you.

For a normal person, the water is locked up inside cell walls and molecules, to the body appears solid. But turn the walls and molecules into powder and all the liquid is unleashed.

Much like the fruit smoothie above. The chunks of fruit look solid but somehow blend into a liquid when you chop them into tiny bits.

The person soup will be thicker than the fruit smoothie. More like mashed potato or banana or porridge. Or maybe refried beans. Yeah beans, that sounds good.

Comment: They will not fall apart into loose atoms. Depending on exactly which molecules have carbons replaced, you'll either get biologically non-functional but stable organosilicon polymers (like silicone rubbers), or unstable silanes which spontaneously react with water (hence the heat) to form solid amorphous silica and hydrogen gas.
Though the end result may still be sandy human soup.

Comment: But only 10% of Carbon atomes get transformed. IF this means the trasmutation is evenly distributed in the body it may cause massive organ failure but no 'smoothification' of a person. The person may actually survive for a while if the transformation mainly invests the outer layers of tissue.

Comment: @DuncanDrake Hmm. . . You might be right. I guess it depends on how big are the molecules. You don't need all the carbons to turn to silicons to have a molecule fall apart. Otherwise it might be similar to putting a person in the freezer and then taking them out.

Comment: From the explanation that I remember, the water is mostly flash boiled away from the intense heat and radiation. "about ten percent of the carbon nuclei in the target are randomly transformed into silicon nuclei as if by magic. Messy pyrotechnics ensue: gamma radiation, short-lived muons, some really pretty high-energy chemistry, and lots of heat." https://thelaundryfiles.fandom.com/wiki/SCORPION_STARE

Comment: @AndyD273, if it's accurate that JUST the nuclei are transformed, then you'd wind up with a massive charge imbalance. You'd definitely see an explosion as 6x10^26 electrons rushed into the body. Stross gets a lot of mileage from the Rule of Cool here.

Comment: @RobertRapplean You're not wrong. The stories have a lot of stuff where circuits that borrow energy and logic processing from other dimensional entities, with an ancient occult language as a programming language for the universe. Basically magic with the rules defined by science, or something that looks enough like science if you squint at it to allow you to suspend disbelief for a while.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer: There would be no apparent petrification, you would just see the human die.**

Carbon in the human body is almost entirely part of organic molecules. So if the silicon just replaces the carbon it would not form any kind of mineral/stone but would just create organosilicon compounds (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosilicon_compound#Silenes). Which look not like stone but more like this:

[image]
This is of course the pure form and regular organic molecules could just like this, when in their pure form. Pretty any process in the body would stop working more or less instantly, since the biochemistry of the organosilicon compounds is quite different. There would be no obvious change to an observer. So the affected person would just drop dead, maybe getting cooked by the heat.

There could be some rupture in the skin due to a lot of dead cells or the heat, but I don't know enough about this to make a prediction here.

Any non-living compound would just change chemical properties and would not serve its original purpose anymore. It could cause a decay, since the covalent bonds of silicon are weaker than with carbon.

Comment: When the carbon atoms are transmuted, large amounts of energy are released, the body is cooked. So your answer should consider that as well. Even without the transmutation, the cooking itself would quickly carbonize the individual and they'd be blackened, crisp. The heat no doubt affects the chemistry of carbon+silicon as well.

Comment: @JohnO Carbonisation only appears to start at 200 deg C (and only really happens at 400 - 500 deg C). Not happening with all that water around. The main effects are jusr as described here, although I think the emphasis on silicones as opposed to amorphous silica is wrong. This answer is good.

Comment: @Matthias Hey do you mind if I change the image to add the Michelin Man eyes and sash to the pile of silenes?

Comment: @Daron I don't mind, go ahead.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you. Now that is one sultry pose, if ever I saw one.

Answer (score 7):

The way to tackle this is to compare carbon and silicon chemically. They contain similar properties as they are both in the same group on the periodic table. Each contains four electrons in its outer shell, meaning it forms four bonds with other atoms. Theoretically, this would mean silicon could serve as a good analog for carbon. Practically, however, there are too many differences for this to be viable:

**1) Size** - silicon atoms have one more shell than carbon, making them much larger. If silicon would replace carbon in the body, there wouldn't be enough space for the atoms. Even if there was, the larger atomic size of silicon means it would mess with bond angles. The carbon-ring formation used throughout the body, including in DNA, likely could not form with silicon. So this could never work for steric reasons.

**2) Polarity** - silicon is more electropositive than carbon. Its extra shell means it has less attraction for electrons, and would therefore be more susceptible to attack by other compounds. Many silicon-based compounds are unstable and spontaneously hydrolyze or combust in water or air. So replacing silicon with carbon in the human body would theoretically result in a minefield.

**3) Reactivity** - silicon's properties make it most stable when bonded with oxygen instead of itself, unlike carbon, which frequently forms long carbon chains in the human body. Because of this, **silicon would likely react with oxygen in the body, forming silica (SiO2) compounds. Interestingly, silica is a solid, found in quartz, sand, and other natural forms, which may explain the stone texture you describe.**

More information on silica vs carbon chemistry could be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7345352/#:%7E:text=3.1.&text=Silicon%20is%20the%20closest%20analogue,(non%2Dionic)%20compounds.). The article discusses the potential of silicon as a building block for life. This sentence is of note in our particular context:

> Si chemistry in oxygen-rich environments (e.g., water) ultimately leads to silica (SiO2) (which is a refractory solid rather than a gas, with no double bonds to oxygen as in its carbon equivalent CO2)

This hopefully answers the question of what kind of stone would be produced by replacing carbon with silicon. However, it must be noted that this is not realistically feasible, due to the size and polarity constraints described. Moreover, as you mentioned, the process of replacing carbon with silicon generates an enormous amount of heat. This could be described as a reaction similar to nuclear fusion, in which two atomic nuclei collide forming a larger atom. This process releases a large amount of energy (think of the heat the sun releases as hydrogen is converted into helium). The human body could never sustain such an amount of energy, and therefore, even ignoring steric/polar constraints, **a person would roast before silicon could react to form solid silica compounds** (aka stone).

Comment: That is in keeping with how the Basilisk guns work in the _Laundry Files_, as anyone unfortunate enough to be in their viewfinders generally explodes.  Those who do not become hot (physically and in terms of radiation) bags of pseudo-concrete.

Comment: Yep.  In the excerpt from *The Rhesus Chart*, at least, the petrification is more or less a side effect - they're using it as a bomb, by basilisking one person from a distance to generate a blast big enough to take out a whole roomful of Things Man Was Not Meant To Know.  (After an explosion that big, it might be a bit unbelievable that the petrified remains are *ever* recognisably person-shaped after the dust has settled, but it's possibly a case of Rule of Cool).

Answer (score 5):

### Burning death, meat spiced with amorphous silica remains

Let's look at the carbon in our bodies for a second.

The *vast* majority of carbons are linked to at least one hydrogen, and very many to two. Sugars, proteins, fats, you name it; they all have empirical formula CHxOy(Other)z, where H >= 1.
Bear this in mind, it's important.

When you swap out carbon atoms like that for silicon atoms, you haven't made silicon carbide or silicones (those require there to be no Si-H bonds). No, you've made silane groups.

Silanes are highly flammable in air and react pretty violently with water under most circumstances.  The slower, controlled reactions a few of you have encountered are exceptions deliberately engineered for that slowness. Silanes with  the weird coordination environments you get in the body are *not* those exceptions, quite the opposite.

BURN!

You immediately cook. You don't explode, although a few small flames erupt on your skin. But the heat capacity of water wins the day here; you don't roast, you stew or maybe boil.

The product of silanes reacting either with aqueous species or air in small amounts is amorphous silica.

The remaining body is partially stewed and a bit gritty, being more than 90% cooked flesh and hot water and a few percent dispersed amorphous silica.

We hope that turning 10% of the brain's carbon into silicon immediately ends cognition before cooking commences, but who knows for sure?

PS Bump the fraction of transmuted carbon well up from 10% and consider swapping some or all of the Si for Ca or Al to get a mineralised body.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the author specified only 10% transmuted if he wanted to end up with something vaguely resembling stone.

Answer (score 2):

### Atomics and other explosions

@Theresa Kay did a perfectly good job of describing the chemistry, but I've always wondered about the basilisk guns. You need to have one of two situations:

1. 10% of carbon gets an extra 8 protons, neutrons, and electrons, or
2. Pairs of C-12 fuse together to form Si-24

The second option is MUCH easier to deal with, as the person would explode. As you work your way up the periodic table, the amount of energy from each step up decreases, so you'll get less than 1/20th of the energy for equivalent hydrogen fusion. On the other hand, [it's been calculated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135013/hydrogen-bomb-mass-to-energy) that a 50MT bomb only fuses about 2.33kg of hydrogen. If we're talking a 100kg human, then you're getting 1.85kg of carbon fusing into silicon. Let's call this something in the 1 megaton range.

However, let's say that such fusion energy was handled by the transformation magic. You'd still have the problem that Si-24 has a half-life of 140ms. Through beta decay, you'd wind up with a lot of magnesium, with traces of neon and sodium. Molecular cohesion would be non-existent, and the thermal effects of beta decay would boil the body instantly. Hot, bloody mist for everybody.

The first one would also result in an explosion, but the magnitude would be far less. A carbon atom is around .09nm in size, but a silicon atom is around .2nm across. The volume of carbon in a human body is roughly 1.1 liters. If turned to Silicon, that would add roughly 6 liters of volume, virtually instantaneously. I can't calculate how big the explosion would be because you can't compress silicon that much. I'm suspecting that we're talking about something that would take down a building.

@Andy273 brought up a horrifying third possibility, based on [the wiki where the basilisk gun is described](https://thelaundryfiles.fandom.com/wiki/SCORPION_STARE). This is where *just the nuclei* of the atoms are replaced, leaving an immense charge imbalance. It would be like lightning in reverse, only worse. Your typical lightning bolt has around ten coulombs of charge. The sudden increase in protons would result in a disparity around a hundred million coulombs.

Comment: You write "pairs of C-12 fuse together to form Si-24". Not sure how that would work. Carbon has 6 protons and silicon has 14. Yet 6+6=12.

Comment: @TheresaKay, I'm presuming that the atomic weight doesn't change, and it has to be silicon so it's 14 protons and 10 neutrons. As mentioned, it's an unstable isotope. 2 of the neutrons have to be broken into proton/electron pairs.

Comment: Not sure I understand your logic. The identity of an atom is determined only by its number of protons. Neutrons are irrelevant. Silicon is only silicon if it has 14 protons, and combining two carbon atoms does not give 14 protons, so it cannot possibly form silicon. You would need to add 2 more protons (perhaps hydrogen) in order to make silicon.

Comment: Are you familiar with beta- decay? https://www.britannica.com/science/beta-decay

Comment: You're right. I missed the next paragraph of your post. Once fused, magnesium could turn into silicon through beta-minus decay, but it would be a messy process with a lot of side reactions - as you noted, not to mention radiation.

Comment: Yea, I wouldn't want to be in the neighborhood for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question has already crossed the line by invoking a third party world, I'll invoke a Douglas Adams type of answer and go with 'bloodstone' to answer the question 'what kind of stone would it produce if used on a human?'

Though, of course, if we want to steer close to the science part of the science-fiction spectrum, we'd have to go with silicon carbide or carborundum.

Comment: I'm not going for the bounty but after I read all the comments, I thought this is a typical '42' question.

Comment: 42? As in the "meaning of life" 42?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

**You would die**

Long answer: Due to carbon's mostly unique property of making bonds to itself, it allows long chain molecules that can store data (y'know, like our good ol' friend DNA) and gives living things energy as glucose. No Carbon, no energy, no information storage, no life.

You could also become a big, human-shaped, highly impure, silica mineral formation if the right combination was in your body

Comment: *Highly* impure - the human body is apparently 70% water, which doesn't contain carbon and thus wouldn't be affected by the basilisk gun, unless there's something the author didn't mention about it affecting oxygen and/or hydrogen as well as carbon.  So it seems like you'd get sandy water, or at most some kind of *very* spongey pumice stone.  Actually, though, checking Wikipedia, some pumice stone apparently *is* 70% or more air.

Comment: Silicon can also build "[molecules sufficiently large to carry biological information.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC33372/)". It's not an ideal substitute, though.

Comment: @A.B. From the explanation that I remember, the water is mostly flash boiled away from the intense heat and radiation. "about ten percent of the carbon nuclei in the target are randomly transformed into silicon nuclei as if by magic. Messy pyrotechnics ensue: gamma radiation, short-lived muons, some really pretty high-energy chemistry, and lots of heat."

Comment: @AndyD273 Makes sense.  I meant most of the mass wouldn't end up as stone.  Small amount of sand or very porous pumice stone and a lot of very hot steam and stray subatomic particles.

Comment: @A.B. Yeah. Another place it mentions that "it appears to an untrained observer as if the target is turned to stone," which is something that would describe most people who might have run into a wild medusae or basilisk in ancient history.